how to importing python class in django case
why we import like this.  from django.db.models import Model,  Model class is inside base.py not models.
expecting  from django.db.models.base import Model,   why base module ommitted.  django/db/models/base.py is the structure

It is reexported in the __init__.py [GitHub], indeed:

from django.db.models.base import DEFERRED, Model  #isort:skip

# …

__all__ = aggregates_all + constraints_all + enums_all + fields_all + indexes_all
__all__ += [
     # …
     "Model",
     # …
]

so you can import it both from the django.db.models.base module, and the django.db.models module: this refers to the same class.
The re-exports typically group some commonly used classes and functions, to make these more accessible.
